# Java - Quick modulus operation

Tags: java

I want to quickly do this:

```
public int myFunc(int n)
{
    for(int i=0; i<=n; i++)
    {
        if(n % i == 0)
            return i;
    }
        return 0;
}
```

With small numbers, it works fine, but on greater ones not. How can I accomplish the same thing, but without the % operator?

Thank you.

Comment: "but on greater ones not" doesn't in *any* way describe what goes wrong. Please explain what happens vs what you want to happen.

Comment: If I set the iterations to 10000000, for example, it takes more than 20 minutes to finish

Comment: does you mean by value greater than integer range?? you can go with BigInteger class.

Comment: return n; ... your function is useless.

Comment: `n%i` will throw an exception when `i==0`

Comment: Right, so it *does* work, but it's slow. That's not the same as not working. Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Pretty sure it *doesn't* work at all.

Comment: Instead of checking `i` from `1` to `n`, check `i` from `1` to `sqrt(n)`. It is obvious that any integer larger than `sqrt(n)` and less than `n` will not be a factor of `n`.

Comment: Based on the title being "quick modulus operation" a reader should be able to infer that the post is related to the speed it takes to perform modulus on large numbers and not the functionality of his method.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly you cannot easily do that quickly.

The fastest way to do it - especially where `int` is being used - would be to run through a list of known primes checking for divisibility.

[Here](http://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/10000.txt) is a list of the first 1000 primes. You could read them in and try each in turn up to `sqrt(n)`.

Something like this:

```
// 10,000 primes - from http://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/10000.txt
private static final ArrayList<Integer> SomePrimes = new ArrayList<>();
private static final String PrimesFileName = "10000Primes.txt";
//private static final String PrimesFileName = "100008Primes.txt";

static {
  try (InputStream in = Primes.class.getResourceAsStream(PrimesFileName);
          InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr)) {
    for (String s; br.ready() && (s = br.readLine()) != null;) {
      // Split into commas.
      String[] ps = s.split(",");
      for (String p : ps) {
        if (p.length() > 0) {
          SomePrimes.add(Integer.valueOf(p));
        }
      }
    }
  } catch (IOException ex) {
    System.err.println("Loading pf primes failed.");
    ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
  }
  //System.out.println("Primes: "+SomePrimes.size());
}

public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
  if (n <= 2) {
    return true;
  }
  int limit = (int) Math.round(Math.sqrt(n));
  for (Integer p : SomePrimes) {
    if (p <= limit) {
      if ((n % p) == 0) {
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```